# How to draw a bar chart from multiple measurements with mean and variance

Tags: pgfplotstable, bar-chart

I have a few hundred measurements in a simple CSV file. I want a bar chart which indicates mean and variance pretty much like this:

[image: Sample bar chart]

I've browsed various archives, such as the [PFG plot gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), but I couldn't find an example that matched the desired outcome.

Imagine my data points to be:

- Drive 1

  - A: 180, 190, 220, 210
  - B: 190, 220, 210, 200
  - C: 290, 320, 310, 300
  - D: 250, 260, 270, 260
  - E: 1250, 1060, 870, 1160
- Drive 2

  - A: 170, 190, 200, 210
  - B: 190, 230, 220, 200
  - C: 280, 330, 320, 290
  - D: 280, 260, 290, 290
  - E: 1350, 1360, 970, 1260
- Drive 3

  - A: 190, 180, 210, 200
  - B: 180, 230, 210, 210
  - C: 480, 430, 420, 490
  - D: 290, 290, 270, 280
  - E: 1550, 1560, 1270, 1560

How would I create a diagram that remotely looks like the one above? Solutions allowing me to provide data in a .csv file are preferred.